# PHP Json decode not work in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a C# client, its send a json to my php server.

There is the json string:

> {"data":[{"name":"1"}]}

Its a valid json. When i try it in PHP Sandbox its works good

```
$ad = '{"data":[{"name":"1"}]}';

$contents = utf8_encode($ad ); 
$results = json_decode($contents); 

var_dump($results->data);
```

But,when i try in laravel 5.1, its not work good.

```
$response = $connection -> getData();
// return $response; (Its equal : {"data":[{"name":"1"}]}   )
$contents = utf8_encode($response);
$results = json_decode($contents);

dd($results->data); // Error Trying to get property of non-object
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: so `var_dump($contents)` **AFTER** you do the utf stuff, and then `echo json_last_error(); var_dump($results)` after the decode attempt. see what really came out.

Comment: JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR

Comment: then skip the utf8 encoding. maybe you're double-encoding or something.

Comment: again error JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR

Comment: What's the class instantiated in that `$connection` variable? Please post the entire code snippet including the part where you setup the connection. Just because you see the same output in the browser when you return the response, doesn't necessarily mean it's encoded properly.

Comment: in getData method just a return socket_read($socket, $dataSize);

Comment: I suggest you post that entire class as well, because we can't guess what might be wrong with it. Also since you're using `socket_read` are you sure the source that it's reading from the C# client is encoded correctly?

Comment: dd($response) : ...␀{␀"␀n␀a␀m␀e␀"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like the `socket_read()` in the `getData()` method is reading 1 character at a time, and then concatenating each NUL terminated character into a response string. `json_decoded()` is choking on all the extra NUL characters.

You can either update your logic in the `getData()` method so it is not doing this, or you can run a str_replace on the results:

```
$response = $connection -> getData();

// get rid of the extra NULs
$response = str_replace(chr(0), '', $response);

$contents = utf8_encode($response);
$results = json_decode($contents);

dd($results->data);
```